# Changing folder permission only not files in linux

Tags: linux, directory, chmod

I am trying to change folder permission on every folder in my site but not the files.

I can list them by doing `ls -l | egrep '^d'`  but is there any way to do this:

`chmod 751 | egrep '^d'`, i get an error as chmod expects 3 params but I'm unsure on how to give it the results from the egrep.

I tried to cheat by using `chmod 751 -R *.*` but I have a few folders with '.' in the name so that won't work.

Answer (score 11):

I guess this should work:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 751 {} \;
```

Comment: Do note that the command is recursive and will execute on subdirs as well (OP's example deals with only the current dir). To limit to the current dir, use the `--maxdepth` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a way of listing the desired items to change you can always wrap it in `$()` (or backticks) to have that bit executed first and placed as parameters, like this:

```
chmod 751 $(ls -l | egrep '^d')
```

Comment: I was taking it from his question but accidentally left out the first bit.

Comment: Another problem with that is it won't properly handle filenames with spaces, and will choke with an "argument list too long" error if there are there are too many files.

Comment: My entire point was in the "if you've got a way of listing the desired items" bit.. He said he'd run it and it showed what he wanted. I was just providing him with a tool that would allow him to use this anywhere, doing anything, not just chmod.

Comment: both seem to work really well. the find one is more appropriate i think but the second $( ) one has fixed something else i wanted.  so thanks guys

Comment: And my point is that using the output of `ls` as arguments of another command is fragile due to the reasons given in the previous comment. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Sure, I get what you're saying, I just think it's irrelevant. He had already verified the output was fine for his use so why fuss about future proofing it for theoretical use cases that do not exist at this stage? I'm all for not writing fragile code, but this is a *one off* terminal operation.

Comment: The comments were meant for other readers who may be looking for a solution. It was not meant to berate your answer.